# Sorting two different tables in a page using tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have to sort two different tables in a page, I have used tablesorter but one table got sorted another one is not. I have used following codes,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.tablesorterPager.defaults.size=document.getElementById("pagesize").value;

    // Org Table
    $("#orgTable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[3,1]]
    }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#orgPager")});;

    // Ter Table
    $("#terTable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[2,1]]
    }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#terPager")});;

});
```

Please suggest me, as orgTable is got sorted  when I click any column header of this table but the terTable is not working.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/heroin62134/xkvr13ht/1/ everything is ok. May be the problem in other place?